# Runtime error 13 when using Trim

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have this bit of VBA that I've used on many Excel workbooks without issues. On a particular workbook, I'm getting a Runtime Error '13': Type Mismatch error as soon as it gets to the `Cell = Trim(Cell)` part. What could be causing this? I've looked through the data, but can't find anything out of the ordinary that would be messing it up.

```
Sub TrimHS()
Application.Cursor = xlWait
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A83:G" & LastRow).Select
Dim rng As Range, Cell As Range
Set rng = Selection

For Each Cell In rng
Cell = Trim(Cell)

Next Cell

Application.Cursor = xlDefault

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error on a particular workbook, thus the `Trim()` gives error `13`, if you are trying to trim it. Make sure that you have no error before trimming:

```
For Each Cell In rng
    If Not IsError(Cell) Then
        Cell = Trim(Cell)
    End If
Next Cell
```

---

To see what is wrong with the code, write `debug.print Cell` before the `Trim` line. It would start printing a lot at the console, the last line to print should look like this: `Error 2007` or similar.

---

This will show the cell with the error in a MsgBox and its Worksheet:

```
For Each Cell In rng
    If Not IsError(Cell) Then
        Cell = Trim(Cell)
    Else
        MsgBox "Error on " & Cell.Address & " in " & Cell.Parent.Name
    End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: Running this doesn't give me an error, but I'm also not able to get any output from using `debug.print Cell`, so I'm not sure how to see what is wrong.

Comment: @Robby - running this should not give you an error indeed. Simply try the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Cell is of type `Excel.Range` and Trim outputs of type `String`

I believe `cell.value=trim(cell.value)` is what you'll need

Comment: Also, `Cell` is an Object - so when you *do* change it, it needs to be `Set`. (E.g. `Set Cell = Nothing`)

Comment: So where do I need to put `cell.value=trim(cell.value)` and where do I put `Set Cell = Nothing`?

Comment: You don't need the nothing bit, replace your troublesome line with mine.

Comment: What is the value of `cell` when you error.  You need to show more details of what is happening on error or show the data.